# Using Twilio how test Sms Sending from php on US number?

Tags: twilio, twilio-php

I want to implement an SMS messaging system (using Twilio account) on my PHP web application using a US Number. So how can I test using a US number?

Comment: Twilio developer evangelist here. I'm not sure what you're asking here. Are you not in the US, but want to send messages to your Twilio number using a US number? Could you give me some more detail please?

Comment: yes , I have created one web app using php it require text message command for registration ,sign up any many more functionality and it based on us phone  number. us client can send text message for for registration.also give it feedback using text message.So messaging Functionality i have use twilio account credential .so for testing purpose how use us number  where i can see functionality work correct.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You have a few options:

Firstly, Twilio numbers, particularly US numbers, are available internationally. So you can test this with your local number, wherever you are.

Alternatively, you could buy a US phone and test with that.

Or, with a bit more work, you could buy a second US Twilio number and build a small app for sending and receiving SMS messages with it and use that number to interact with your first Twilio number.

Let me know if this helps at all!

Comment: I have sent message to twilio free number from my number (i.e. india) ,but i didin't get response from twilio , I have tried following code for receiving message :-

Comment: <?php                                                                             header("content-type: text/xml");
    echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";
?>
<Response>
    <Message><?php echo $name ?>, thanks for the message!</Message>
</Response>

Comment: Also I have set path of receiving file for that free number. please help my where i got stuck ..thanks in advance..

Comment: You can check whether your message arrived at Twilio in the Monitor in your account dashboard. You should be able to see what's going on from there.